# How to programatically enter text into an Angular INPUT element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got an Angular web-page (3rd party). The page has an INPUT field that accepts 3-letter airport identifier. Once a user types the correct 3-letter identifier - it automatically expands it into long form. e.g. SFO > San Francisco.

The problem is that, if I just set the value of the INPUT element to SFO programmatically (i.e. `element.value='SFO'` - this translation doesn't get triggered. Only if it's entered by keyboard.

This is how the element is declared:

```
<input class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted ng-touched" dropdowntoggle="" maxlength="3" placeholder="Enter city or airport" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
```

How can I emulate a keyboard and send the 3-letters to the INPUT element?

Looking for a pure Javascript solution. My JS code will be injected into the above page (e.g. extension script).

Comment: You can use ngModel.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [autocomplete input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ng-autocomplete)